# Kotlin -FusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates LocationRequest Param Error

Tags: kotlin, parameters, google-location-services

I'm trying to add a LocationRequest as the first `parameter` to `fusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates` but I keep getting an error

> None of the following function can be called with the arguments
> supplied.
>
> • requestLocationUpdates(LocationRequest, LocationCallback, Looper?)
> defined in com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient
>
> None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied:
>
> public abstract fun requestLocationUpdates(p0: LocationRequest, p1:
> LocationCallback, p2: Looper?): Task<Void!> defined in
> com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient
>
> public
> abstract fun requestLocationUpdates(p0: LocationRequest, p1:
> LocationListener, p2: Looper?): Task<Void!> defined in
> com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient
>
> public
> abstract fun requestLocationUpdates(p0: LocationRequest, p1: Executor,
> p2: LocationCallback): Task<Void!> defined in
> com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient
>
> public
> abstract fun requestLocationUpdates(p0: LocationRequest, p1: Executor,
> p2: LocationListener): Task<Void!> defined in
> com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient

As you can see in the picture, `LocationCallback` and `Looper?` work fine. I'm using the first suggestion, which `LocationRequest` is red.

[image]

I followed the google [doc code](https://developer.android.com/training/location/request-updates?hl=en) for startLocationUpdates(), and that's where the error is located below.

In the Manifest I tried both of these separately:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.1@aar'
```

Code:

```
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.location.*
import android.location.LocationRequest
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Looper
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
import com.google.android.gms.location.*
import java.util.*
import android.provider.Settings

class LocationSupervisor(val context: Context) {

    private var fusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context.applicationContext)
    private lateinit var locationRequest: LocationRequest
    private lateinit var locationCallback: LocationCallback

    init {

        fusedLocationClient.lastLocation.addOnSuccessListener { }

        locationRequest = LocationRequest.Builder(60000L).apply {
            this.setQuality(LocationRequest.QUALITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
        }.build()

        locationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
            override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult) {
                for (location in locationResult.locations) { ... }
            }
        }
    }

    fun startLocationUpdates() {
                                     // Error is on this 1st Param
        fusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, Looper.getMainLooper())
    }

    fun stopLocationUpdates() {
        fusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You have wrong import.**

At first correct the import

> import android.location.LocationRequest ❌
>
> **import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest** ✅

Then use this code for location request:

```kotlin
locationRequest = LocationRequest.Builder(60000L)
            .setPriority(Priority.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
            .build()
```

Also, I suggest using my open source library.

```
implementation("com.github.GatewayLegends:general-location-service:0.1.4")
```

You can find the General Location Service on GitHub at the following link: https://github.com/GatewayLegends/general-location-service

I encourage you to explore the repository, review the documentation, and try it out in your projects. I am confident that you will find it to be a valuable asset that saves you time and effort in your location-based operations.
put star on Github if you see it useful, and upvote this answer.

If you find the General Location Service useful, I kindly request that you consider showing your support by starring it on GitHub. Additionally, if you appreciate this suggestion, an upvote would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your consideration!

Comment: It worked, thanks. In addition, I was able to use `this.setGranularity(Priority.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)`. I starred your repo :). Cheers!!!